# Webapp displaying database error when registering with already existing user using Python Flask

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I am using Flask over Python for developing a login system.

When the user registers with an existing username, instead of returning an error message it's returning the database error, **which is a security flaw**.

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
  form = RegisterForm(request.form)
  if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    email = form.email.data
    password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(str(form.password.data))
    cursor=db.cursor()
    if cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user(email, password) VALUES(%s ,%s)", (email, password)):
        db.commit()
        flash('Success','success')
    else:
        flash('Success','error')
    cursor.close()
    redirect(url_for('index'))

  return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

How can I control the message it returns?

Comment: Show us the traceback

Comment: I don't see where you checked if the user exists before trying to insert him in the DB

Comment: You really shouldn't try to implement something like this yourself, especially if you're concerned about security. Use one of the many third-party packages available for Flask.

Answer (score 0):

Improve your insert statement to handle already existing values:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO user(email, password) VALUES(%s ,%s)')
```

This way there will be no DB error, and you could handle it according to the return value.

Comment: Tried, getting no errors now.Error message still not displaying